# Why did Makuta make every effort to ensure that his ultimate plan did NOT succeed?

Tags: bionicle

Why did he keep the Matoran holed up on the island of Mata Nui for a thousand years, when he really wanted them to return to Metru Nui, and doing this only gave Turaga Dume a chance to rebuild the city? Why did he and the other Makuta try to prevent the Toa Nuva from accessing the Codrex, when he really wanted them to enter so that he could take over the Matoran Universe?

Granted, he didn't want them to know that this was his ultimate plan (he wanted them to think they were winning) but the description of the battle doesn't sound like they're feigning loss.

Comment: I don't recall the answer to the first part about the Matoran and Turaga Dume, but as far as the second part goes, I seem to recall it being said that he lied to his fellow Makuta so that they would think they were meant to fight the Toa and keep them away from the Codrex, even though in reality they were just being used to buy Teridax time to get to the Core Processor, which would also result in them being stuck in Karda Nui when the energy storms started. It would be convenient for Teridax for them all to be dead because then none of them could challenge his power.

Comment: @Amy Krika was the exception. He knew of Teridax's plan, even offering mercy and imploring Gali to abandon her efforts. I suppose his participation in the final battle was an effort to kill the Toa Nuva and prevent them from enacting their plan. But other than that, this makes sense.

Comment: Wasn't it Terdidax's intent to keep the Matoran dormant in Metru Nui, and his plans were interrupted due to his temporary defeat by the Toa Metru and their "Great Rescue" of the Matoran to Mata Nui?